# Unable to establish Handshake with Public Websocket API for Kraken

Tags: javascript, websocket, get, handshake

I'm trying to make a watchlist for cryptocurrency tickers You type a ticker, add it, and it will show you real time prices in a table format.

My first step is to try and establish a handshake connection with the Kraken websocket API (documentation here: https://www.kraken.com/features/websocket-api#connectionDetails)

**My ask:**
At the moment, all I want to do is be able to console log a "connection success" for when I'm connected with the websocket API from Kraken (crypto exchange). I'm trying to do this via the portion below (**scroll all the way down to see all of the code**)

```
  socket.onopen = function(event) {
  socketStatus.innerHTML = 'Connected to: ' + event.currentTarget.url;
  socketStatus.className = 'open';
};
```

I've got an index.html file, and an app.js file. When I open the index.html file in chrome, I get an error:

**app.js:5 WebSocket connection to 'ws://ws-sandbox.kraken.com/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 521**

I've tried with only this line of code for websocket related stuff

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://ws-sandbox.kraken.com')
```

I've also tried to use the get method, provided in examples from here
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/here-is-the-most-popular-ways-to-make-an-http-request-in-javascript-954ce8c95aaa

```
$.get('ws://ws-sandbox.kraken.com',function(data){console.log(`${data}`)})
```

in my app.js file, my question is, apart from line below what else do I need to successfully do the handshake? Do I need to send a GET request with header information (please see very end)?

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://ws-sandbox.kraken.com')
```

in the documentation, you'll see connection details. Connection details for sandbox environment. The URL is ws-sandbox.kraken.com
link: https://www.kraken.com/features/websocket-api#connectionDetails

I've followed the example here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

GET REQUEST QUESTION: 
I was looking at this site as an example: 
https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/an-introduction-to-websockets

and it said I need to send an HTTP request to the server using something similar to this. I'm just not sure if this is required for what I'm trying to do.

```
GET ws://websocket.example.com/ HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://example.com
Connection: Upgrade
Host: websocket.example.com
Upgrade: websocket
```

CODE IN APP.JS FILE

```
$(document).ready(function(){ console.log('page ready')


var socket = new WebSocket('ws://ws-sandbox.kraken.com')

$.get('ws://ws-sandbox.kraken.com',function(data){console.log(`${data}`)})

  var form = document.getElementById('message-form');
  var messageField = document.getElementById('message');
  var messagesList = document.getElementById('messages');
  var socketStatus = document.getElementById('status');
  var closeBtn = document.getElementById('close');

socket.onopen = function(event) { //LOGGING SUCCESSFUL CONNECTION HERE
  socketStatus.innerHTML = 'Connected to: ' + event.currentTarget.url;
  socketStatus.className = 'open';
};
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I was having the same issue and wanted to provide my solution in case anyone else comes here in need of it.

So the reason I found for this error was because I using a protocol that was not supported by the API. I was using TLS 1.0 where the Kraken API only supports 1.2/1.3:

https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023264371-TLS-upgrade-that-might-affect-your-API-connections

So to solve it, I simply set my websocket client to use TLS 1.2 as the protocol.

Comment: Well for my case the problem was using ws:// istead of wss:// which indicates tls underneath. But you gave me the idea that could have been something TLS related so +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

From a browser, using the [Websocket()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) built-in api:

```js
new WebSocket("wss://ws.kraken.com").onopen = function(){
  this.onclose = () => console.log("SOCKET CLOSED")
  this.onmessage = (e) => console.log(JSON.parse(e.data))
  this.send(JSON.stringify({
      "event": "subscribe",
      "pair": ["XBT/USD"],
      "subscription": {
        "interval": 1,
        "name": "ohlc"
      }
  }), (e) => console.log(e))
}
```